# How to change the shell's viewmodel property from within a page?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I am working with `durandaljs` and loading a `shell` view which in turn then loads an internal view: `page1`. I am binding certain items within the `shell`, which I would like to be changeable from within the inner views: i.e. `page1`. Example:

`shell.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <div data-bind="text: someValue"></div>
  <section id="content" class="main container-fluid">
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
        afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
        transition: 'entrance'} -->
    <!--/ko-->
  </section>
</div>
```

`shell.js`

```
define(['durandal/plugins/router', 'global'],
function (router, global) {
  function activate() {
    global.shellViewModel = shell;
    return router.activate('page1');
  }
  var shell = {
    //...
    someValue: ko.observable('hello world'),
    activate: activate
  };
  return shell;
});
```

`page1.js`

```
define(['durandal/plugins/router', 'global', 'viewmodels/shell'],
function (router, global, shell) {
  function activate() {
    return;
  }
  var page1SomeValue = ko.computed(function() {
    shell.someValue('hello world');
  });
  var vm = {
    //...
    activate: activate,
    somePage1Value: somePage1Value
  };
  return vm;
});
```

When `page1` gets loaded the `global.shellViewModel.someValue('hello world');` gets executed, but the value on the `shell` view doesn't change. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know whether it solves your current problem but you should consider to use the pub/sub features of durandal http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe/ especially the application wide messaging instead of passing a global object around.

Comment: @nemesv I was not aware of that feature. I looked around and there were people recommending to pass a global module with the objects. Thanks for the recommendation! I will give it a try, but I doubt that will solve it.

Comment: @nemesv thank you for your introduction events, but as I suspected, it didn't work. For some reason changing the observable is not refreshing the binding

Comment: What is global? What is global.shellViewModel? The shell's viewmodel is shell.js and is represented in your code by " var shell ".

Comment: @JohnPapa `global` is a module for storing global variables that I can use across modules. I store the `shell`'s VM in there and access it on the `page1`'s viewmodel. But it is not rebinding.

Comment: There is no reason I can think of to store the viewmodel in a global. Durandal let's you resolve modules, so if you need the shell viewmodel, just "require" it. I suspect there is something wrong with the way "global" is being used. Just make sure you shell view model is a singleton, if you want that exact instance of that vm (that is what I chose in the CodeCamper demo)

Comment: @JohnPapa I tried your suggestion and I like that one the most out of all possible ways of passing data around. The problem had to do with `somevalue` being set inside a computed observable of the `page1` vm. For whatever reason it wasn't refreshing the view. I changed the code to a `setTimeout` and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I forgot to mention on the initial question was the `somevalue` was being set inside a `ko.computed` property of the `page1` VM and for whatever reason it was causing some sort of clash when refreshing the `page1` and the `shell` view. I fixed the issue by setting the `shell.somevalue('hello world');` inside a `setTimeout` like so:

```
var page1SomeValue : ko.computed(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //shell is required by page1 viewmodel
    shell.someValue('hello world from page 1');
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Be careful with setTimeout. I'd love to see the code and see if there is another way to do that. Might work here, but I wouldnt trust it.

Comment: I wish I could host it with jsfiddle, but don't know how to use jsfiddle and Durandal

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments that events are not working either there might be an issue with the way `someValue` is declared. Did you try to declare `someValue` outside of `shell` and then populate it within `activate()`?

```
define(['durandal/plugins/router', 'global'],
function (router, global) {
  var someValue = ko.observable('');
  var shell = {
    //...
    someValue: someValue
    activate: activate
  };
  return shell;

  function activate() {
    someValue('greeting from shell');
    global.shellViewModel = shell;

    return router.activate('page1');
  }
});
```

Comment: as a matter of fact that's exactly how it's coded and not working. The question is shown like that for brevity. Does this work for you?

Comment: Sure thing. Even better I used your question as a test case for something that I'm working on. So you can see an online version at http://rainerat.spirit.de/so16363046/#/ and all JS and HTML files at https://github.com/RainerAtSpirit/so16363046/tree/gh-pages/App

Feel free to fork and fiddle around.

Answer (score 0):

Working example at http://rainerat.spirit.de/so16363046/#/

As I don't see any substantial differences with the code pasted vs. working version my assumption is that there's a difference in global.js:

```
define(function () {
    global = {};


    return global;
});
```